# Display 3D model online

Tags: javascript, 3d, webgl, autocad

How can a 3D model of a building design file, any format, ifc or collada be displayed online?

Answer (score 3):

You may want to look into [WebGL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebGL), a 3D rendering API for Javascript. [ThreeJS](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/) is another excellent library for in-browser 3D rendering. Again, Javascript.

It's even possible to render "3D" stuff with CSS, as shown in this [excellent article](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/08/rendering-3d-with-css-and-javascript-with-dom3d-guest-post/).